# Shrinking Menu Html/CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, menu, navbar

I'm a beginner ( in code and in English..!), so forgive my question that haunts me and may be easy for a good developer!

I coded a navbar that shrinks when the user scrolls down and go down to normal when the user scrolls back up.
Apparently, it does work.
So I started to copy the code of my menu in the beginning of the pages of the other pages of the site.
The problem: when we click on a link to another page, we go to this page, but there is an unwelcome move of the items of the menu in the new page from the right of the screen to their correct places.

**This is the index.html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sacramento&family=Signika:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Accueil</title>
</head>
<body>

<header id="main-header" class="shrink">
  <nav>
  <a href="index.php"><img id="logo" src="assets/ART_T_Blanc.svg"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="moi.php">Who I am</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ethics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section class="Desktop">
  <div class="contentAccueil">
    <p>Content 01</p>
    <p>Content 02</p>
    <p>Content 03</p>
</div>


<footer class="FooterDesktop">
  <hr />
  <p><small><em>Created by iDamira using tutsplus.com tutorial.</em></small></p>
</footer>

<section>
    


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the moi.php page with the same code for the menu:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sacramento&family=Signika:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Accueil</title>
</head>
<body>

<header id="main-header" class="shrink">
  <nav>
  <a href="index.php"><img id="logo" src="assets/ART_T_Blanc.svg"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="moi.php">Qui suis-je?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pratique de l'Art-Thérapie</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mes Actualités</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tarifs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section class="Desktop">
  <div class="contentAccueil">
    <p>Moi 01</p>
    <p>Moi 02</p>
    <p>Moi 03</p>
</div>


<footer class="FooterDesktop">
  <hr />
  <p><small><em>Created by iDamira using tutsplus.com tutorial.</em></small></p>
</footer>

<section>
    


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the css:**

```
* {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
body {
    color: #333;
}
  
hr {
    margin: 3em 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    border: none;
}
  
p {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
  
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 85%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
  
  /* header */
  
header {

    
    padding: 0 2em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #333;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6.5em;
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}


header #logo {

    width: 100px; /* Taille initiale du logo */
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
 
 
    transition: width 0.8s ease-in-out, height 0.8s ease-in-out; /* Ajoutez la transition pour la largeur et la hauteur du logo */
}
  
  nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;  
}
  
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 1em;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 6em;
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}
  
/* #logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
} */



/* Reduction Menu: */

.contentAccueil p {
    height: 100vh;
}
          
header.shrink {
    height: 4.5em;
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}
          
header.shrink nav ul li {
    line-height: 4em; 
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}


header.shrink #logo {
    width: 70px; /* Nouvelle largeur du logo lorsque l'en-tête est réduit */
    height: 70px; /* Nouvelle hauteur du logo lorsque l'en-tête est réduit */
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
    
  }
        


/* Fin Menu Desktop */



  
/* ContentAccueil */
  
.contentAccueil{
    margin: 10em auto 0;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**And at las the script.js code:**

```
var windowElement = window;
var mainHeader = document.getElementById("main-header");

windowElement.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    if (windowElement.scrollY > 100) {
        mainHeader.classList.add("shrink");
    } else if (mainHeader.classList.contains("shrink")) {
        mainHeader.classList.remove("shrink");
    }
});
```

Can someone help me please?

I do not know what to try..

Thank You!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

so I will explain why the issue is happening first.
You want to make a transition back and forward so you put a lot of transitions and some of them occurs in the "initial" code.
Transition in css means the css you added is appearing in animation and if you put a transition on the header or on a class that already assigned in the html so it will appear in a transition movement to the screen.

The way to solve this issue is to make sure there is no transition styling on any tag or class that should appear when the page is first loaded.

I try to remove and change your current CSS, HTML and JavaScript so it will prevent this transitions in the page load up.

**This is the current HTML:**
In the HTML I basically just removed the shrink class from the header

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sacramento&family=Signika:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Accueil</title>
</head>
<body>

<header id="main-header" class="">
  <nav>
  <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="assets/ART_T_Blanc.svg"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="moi.html">Who I am</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ethics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section class="Desktop">
  <div class="contentAccueil">
    <p>Content 01</p>
    <p>Content 02</p>
    <p>Content 03</p>
</div>


<footer class="FooterDesktop">
  <hr />
  <p><small><em>Created by iDamira using tutsplus.com tutorial.</em></small></p>
</footer>

<section>
    


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the current CSS:**
I leave the unwanted transitions in a comment.

```css
* {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
body {
    color: #333;
}
  
hr {
    margin: 3em 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    border: none;
}
  
p {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
  
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 85%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
  
  /* header */
  
header {

    
    padding: 0 2em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #333;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6.5em;
    /* transition: all .8s ease-in-out; */
}

header #logo {

    width: 100px; /* Taille initiale du logo */
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
 
 
    /* transition: width 0.8s ease-in-out, height 0.8s ease-in-out; Ajoutez la transition pour la largeur et la hauteur du logo */
}
  
  nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;  
}
  
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 1em;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 6em;
    /* transition: all .8s ease-in-out; */
}
  
/* #logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
} */



/* Reduction Menu: */

.contentAccueil p {
    height: 100vh;
}
          
header.shrink {
    height: 4.5em;
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}
          
header.shrink nav ul li {
    line-height: 4em; 
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}


header.shrink #logo {
    width: 70px; /* Nouvelle largeur du logo lorsque l'en-tête est réduit */
    height: 70px; /* Nouvelle hauteur du logo lorsque l'en-tête est réduit */
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
    
  }
        


/* Fin Menu Desktop */



  
/* ContentAccueil */
  
.contentAccueil{
    margin: 10em auto 0;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**This is the current JavaScript:**
Im pretty sure its the same but for any case.

```js
var windowElement = window;
var mainHeader = document.getElementById("main-header");

windowElement.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    if (windowElement.scrollY > 100) {
        mainHeader.classList.add("shrink");
    } else if (mainHeader.classList.contains("shrink")) {
        mainHeader.classList.remove("shrink");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

By the way, there's probably a lot of other ways make this that are more simple and are better practice to do. I recommend you to search on the internet for other people that try to create the same effect, it might improve your final result.

Comment: Hello Barak,    I thank you very much for solving my problem!  Thanks to you i understood what Ihave done wrong. Have a great week end! Didier